# Can we nest bootstrap container in ASP.NET MVC view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

As per the bootstrap documentaion

> Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and
>   house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use in
>   your projects. Note that, due to padding and more, neither container
>   is nestable.

In ASP.NET MVC we have layout.cshtml page which typically includes container. and all other views gets rendered inside the this container.
Does that mean we cannot use 'container' in the individual view?

Comment: Yes you are correct. If you think you need different structures for different pages you can always create additional layouts.Actually what you call 'individual view' will be children or partial views of that layout right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on your layout structure and what you want to achieve. There are 2 ways to accomplish this (I can't think of any more).

I don't use containers in my `_Layout.cshtml` template. I normally have my containers in my views. My `_Layout.cshtml` template only has the bare minimum.

This is what my `_Layout.cshtml` template normally looks like:

```
<body>
     @RenderBody()
     @Html.Partial("_Footer")
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/js")
     @RenderSection("scripts", false)
</body>
```

And then in my views I would have the following:

```
<div class="container">
     <p>Test paragraph</p>
</div>
```

You can also have the container in your `_Layout.cshtml` template but then in your views you must just remember that you already have a container that you are working with. So your `_Layout.cshtml` it could look like this:

```
<body>
     <div class="container">
         @RenderBody()
     </div>
     @Html.Partial("_Footer")
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/js")
     @RenderSection("scripts", false)
</body>
```

And then your view could look like this:

```
<p>Test paragraph</p>
```

The best way to see what will work in your scenario is to play around with the various positionings of the containers and the other HTML components. It will take a while but it will give you an indication of what is possible and what is not.